# Problem with Dependencies "Analyzers" in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

I have this problem with Visual Studio, I tried to uninstall Visual Studio and install it again but it doesn't work.

From what I see, the route of the "analyzers" is not the correct one, if someone knows how to solve it, I would appreciate it.

Visual Studio

[image: 1]

I tried to uninstall Visual Studio and install it again but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

For me I was able to fix by going to the properties of the project and selecting the Analysis Level to be either the specific version you want to use or "Latest Recommended".  And the problems went away.

After I did a build, I was able to go back and change the setting back to "Latest" without the issues returning.

[image: Screenshot of Code Analysis Properties]

Comment: In my project, there is a analyzer dependency that no longer exist and gives me a warning, but I am unable to remove it from the project dependencies. This fixed it for me. Thanks!